# How to show custom devise params in erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
<%= simple_form_for [ @user ,@tweet], id: "form-submit" do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :content, label: "Tweet" %>
   <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
   <% end %>

   <br>

<% @tweets.each do |tweet|  %>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= tweet.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y, %l:%M%P") %> <br>
      <%= tweet.content %>
      <%= tweet.user.email %>

    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

I'm making a twitter clone. I'm trying to show a users username next to their tweet. I'm using devise and I've made it so a user enters a first name, last name and username on a sign in. however, they are appearing as nil on rails console, not sure what the issue is as I thought that everything that I added to the application controller was correct. it works when I do tweet.user.email though.

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true , input_html: { autocomplete: "First Name" }%>
  <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true , input_html: { autocomplete: "Last Name" }%>
  <%= f.input :username, required: true, autofocus: true , input_html: { autocomplete: "Username" }%>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true , input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length), input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
</div>
```

and my application controller is:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    # For additional fields in app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :username])

    # For additional in app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :username])
  end
end
```

Comment: so you checked this sample of use? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address